# Can't switch keyboard layout in xfce

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout

I have added a new keyboard layout in keyboard settings. I have added the language applet to my toolbar as well. Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does not change anything.

[image]

I also added the corresponding language packages in the language and locale settings.
[image]
[image]

It does nothing. Even in the keyboard settings in "Manjaro settings manager", testing the layout also fails. It types in English.
[image]

Can someone help me fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indian Kannada layout does not work on my computer either.

I found a topic that seems similar:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-unable-to-set-keyboard-layout-to-indian/

From this topic, looks like many Indian layouts got broken with one recent update in Manjaro:

> Indian language variants of the keyboard layout have stopped working after this update. Please take a look at this post.

I guess, it may be worth switching to testing to receive the fix:
`sudo pacman-mirrors --api --set-branch testing`